# DAWG Vs Radix Tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Which data structure is better at creating a dictionary based text editor? DAWG or Radix Tree?
Please give your analysis based on their ease of creation vs there speed; also provide any links if you can on how could i create these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve although:-

DAWG has an advantage of memory utilization.

Radix tree performs insertion, deletion and searching in O(k) time which is O(logn) in Balanced trees.

Comment: I want to suggest words for autocompletion based on there frequency of use; and it should be as fast as possible? Could you suggest me a way of creating a DAWG?

Comment: Could you please explain this autocompletion term?

Comment: Please refer this link...http://code.google.com/p/dawgdic/wiki/Readme Hope that helps you. And dont forget to accept the answer!!! happy coding.